# use or print pointer value in c

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I want to use or print the value of pointer dp that is supposed to contain certain byte from a file but it says: **"segmentation fault (core dumped)"** Also if I want to print "m" or "n" I get the same error message. how can I use the value of pointers m, n, dp? I just changed %s to %f it says the same message.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void read_file( char * s, int * mp, int * np, double ** dpp )
{
    int m, n ;
    double * dp ;
    FILE * fp ;

    fp = fopen ( s, "r" ) ;
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"read_file(): Unable to open file '%s'\n", s ) ;
        exit(12) ;
    }

    fread( &m, sizeof(int), 1, fp ) ;
    fread( &n, sizeof(int), 1, fp ) ;

    /*   printf("m = %d, n = %d\n", m, n ) ;  */
    dp = (double *) malloc( m * n * sizeof(double) ) ;
    if (dp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"read_file(): malloc failed for %d bytes on file '%s'\n", m*n*sizeof(double), s ) ;
            exit(13) ;
    }

    fread( dp, sizeof(double), m*n, fp ) ;
    fclose (fp) ;

    *mp = m ;  *np = n ;
    *dpp = dp ;
}

int main()
{

    char *s="g.dat";
    int *m;int *n;
    double *dp;

    read_file(s,m,n,&dp);

    printf("it crashes here... %f\n",*dp);  
}
```

it crashes on printf("printing ... %f\n",*dp); with the same segmentation fault message.

Comment: Besides using a (possible) uninitialized pointer, you are printing it as a string (format `%s`) when it's a double (format `%f`).

Comment: show us the implementation of `read_file`. In particular how you are using `dpp`.

Comment: Why did you remove everything from `read_file()`?  What it's doing will likely inform the answers about how to handle the parameters passed to it. Also, there's a good chance that there's stuff in there that needs fixed.

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for m & n? Maybe it is crashing at the end of the function when you assign m & n to *mp & *np. You could try  `int m;int n;` ... `read_file(s,&m,&n,&dp);`?

Comment: read_file(s,&m,&n,&dp) doesn't work either but when I place the the content of function read_file inside my main function it works it gives m=256, and dp=0.033 or something but I think the problem appears when I use an outside function read_file

Comment: What is the documented behavior of the 'outside' `read_file()`?

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is the specifier for a string (e.g. `char *`), and you give it a double, which is not a valid char pointer of course. to print double, use `%f`

Regarding printing the names of the variables - this is not possible in C, as the compile removes the variable names. you can do it using macros though:

```
#define NAME_AND_VAL(X) #X, X
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int a = 1;
    int * b = &a;
    printf("%s = %d\n", NAME_AND_VAL(a));
    printf("%s = %d\n", NAME_AND_VAL(*b));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
a = 1
*b = 1
```

Comment: Thanks but I just changed from %s to %f it keeps saying segmentation fault ( core dumped)

Comment: @Percy - you added a new code, where do you get the crash? (add prints to see where do you get)

Comment: I get the crash on the last printf instruction in main.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error since you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. `dp` is declared, but never changed in `read_file`.

As it is now, it's just a dangling pointer, I don't see what printing its value would accomplish.

```
 printf("printing ... %s\n",*dp);
```

Also, `*dp` returns a `double`, but you're telling `printf` to expect a `const char*` via `%s`.

Answer (score -1):

pointers are error prone, most of pointer runtime errors are due to not intialize  them correctly. and using them before assigning address.